# Read and write PVR Textures in python

Tags: python, image, textures

I'm trying to create a program that is able to read and write PVR Textures. I don't need to be able to render them in a game, I just need to be able to read and write them, similar to what PIL does. I'm fine with converting the PVR Texture to PNG, and vice verca, I just need to be able to do it in python.

I've done a lot of research, and it seams like there is a PVRTexLibPy module that was created by PowerVR, but I can't find it anywhere.